# Robot().createScreenCapture captures image with print dialog in it

Tags: java

I would like my application to take a screenshot and present a print dialog so that the user can print the screenshot. However, the screenshot is being taken too slowly/the dialog appears too quickly, resulting in the dialog appearing in the screenshot (shown below).

[image]

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle((int) frame.getLocationOnScreen().getX(), (int) frame.getLocationOnScreen().getY(), frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()));

...

if (printJob.printDialog()) {
    try {
        printJob.print();
    } catch (Exception PrintException) {
        PrintException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Instead of using an artificial Thread.sleep(), is there a way to indicate when the screenshot is finished capturing before displaying the print dialog?

---

**EDIT :**

OK, I think I figured out what I did wrong. What was really going on was that the screen was being captured after the print dialog displays and the user clicks OK, but before the print dialog animates away. This was due to the following code:

```
// Print button action listener
public class printButtonPressed implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob ();
        Book book = new Book ();
        PageFormat documentPageFormat = new PageFormat ();
        documentPageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
        book.append(new Page(), documentPageFormat);
        printJob.setPageable(book);

        if (printJob.printDialog()) {
            try {
                printJob.print();
            } catch (Exception PrintException) {
                PrintException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Create printable page
private class Page implements Printable {
    public int print (Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) {

        JFrame frame = Main.frame;
        try { // THIS SHOULD NOT BE HERE
            screenShot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle((int) frame.getLocationOnScreen().getX(), (int) frame.getLocationOnScreen().getY(), frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate (pageFormat.getImageableX (), pageFormat.getImageableY ());

        int pageWidth = (int) pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
        int newImageWidth = pageWidth;
        int newImageHeight = (int)((double)newImageWidth/screenShot.getWidth(null)*screenShot.getHeight(null));

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g2d.drawImage(screenShot, 0, 0, newImageWidth, newImageHeight, 0, 0, screenShot.getWidth(), screenShot.getHeight(), null);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Instead if Robot().createScreenCapture was called before any of the PrinterJob stuff, then the screen would be captured before the print dialog appears, resolving this issue.

```
// Print button action listener
public class printButtonPressed implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        JFrame frame = Main.frame;
        try { // MOVE THIS UP HERE
            screenShot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle((int) frame.getLocationOnScreen().getX(), (int) frame.getLocationOnScreen().getY(), frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob ();
        Book book = new Book ();
        PageFormat documentPageFormat = new PageFormat ();
        documentPageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
        book.append(new Page(), documentPageFormat);
        printJob.setPageable(book);

        if (printJob.printDialog()) {
            try {
                printJob.print();
            } catch (Exception PrintException) {
                PrintException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Create printable page
private class Page implements Printable {
    public int print (Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate (pageFormat.getImageableX (), pageFormat.getImageableY ());

        int pageWidth = (int) pageFormat.getImageableWidth();
        int newImageWidth = pageWidth;
        int newImageHeight = (int)((double)newImageWidth/screenShot.getWidth(null)*screenShot.getHeight(null));

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g2d.drawImage(screenShot, 0, 0, newImageWidth, newImageHeight, 0, 0, screenShot.getWidth(), screenShot.getHeight(), null);

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you do something like creating a second dialog saying its done and when that's closed, it moves on to printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dump it into an array then parse the entire array then you can guarantee that everything is there

what I mean is this

```
BufferedImage TestShot = iris.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0,0,width,height));
int[] ImgData = null;
TestShot.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, ImgData, 0, 0);
for(int i:ImgData){
    // count or something
}
// all of it is there in TestShot
```

That should work. I don't know why you are having problems with this, I use the robot all the time and the screenshot function for me works instantly. Maybe its your printJob that takes more time.

Comment: Iterating over the array will have no effect whatsoever (except maybe slow down your code). You can safely remove that part.

Comment: the reason I left that in there is because it would throw a array in there is because if it ran zero times then you know that there is no data in the array and the screenshot should not be ready at that point, what you could do is add a small counter and if the counter is above ten or something break out. Just to double check that the data is all there.

Comment: Resolved my issue (see my edits above). Thanks for the help but it was happening for another reason!